# Export mysql database of openshift

Tags: mysql, database, export, openshift

I am trying to export mysql database hosted on openshift, I have taken the free account and do not have access to OpenShift CLI.Is there any other way I can get my database exported from OpenShift?

Comment: You really need to be able to use the ``oc`` client so have access to port fowarding. See https://learn.openshift.com/introduction/port-forwarding/ Why don't have you have access to the CLI?

Comment: I am using the trial version of openshift, that does'nt let me allow to download Openshift CLI.

Comment: The OpenShift CLI is always free, one of the benefits of open source. When you say "trial version", are you referring to OpenShift Online Pro Trial? Or a self-installed trial of OCP? Either way, you should be able to access the CLI from the "?" drop down in the upper right of the website. Or, worst case scenario, just download it directly from GitHub https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases.